# Invariants and subgroups

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $G$ be an affine algebraic group over some algebraically closed field $K$, and let $H$ be a closed subgroup.
Assume that $G$ acts algebraically on an affine variety $X$. 
Assume that $X'\subseteq X$ is a closed subvariety such that $h(X')=X'$ for every $h\in H$, and such that the following condition holds:
If $Y=G\cdot x$ is a $G$-orbit in $X$, then $Y\cap X'$ is an $H$-orbit in $X'$ ( a priori it might be a union of orbits or empty).
We then have an induced algebra map $K[X]^G\to K[X']^H$ induced by the restriction of functions.
This map is injective, due to the fact that every orbit in $X$ intersects $X'$ nontrivially.

> **Question**: Is this map also surjective?

For every $f\in K[X']^H$ there exists a unique extension to a $G$-invariant function $\tilde{f}:X\to K$, given by $\tilde{f}(x) = \tilde{f}(g\cdot x)$ for some $g\in G$ such that $g\cdot x\in X'$ (this is well defined by the conditions we have on the action). 
Is this map always polynomial? If so, how can one prove it? If not, what would be a counterexample? Can we prove anything more specific if we assume, for example, that $G$ or $H$ (or both) are reductive?

Correction, following the remark of YCor: Assume also that the orbits of $G$ in $X$ are closed.

Comment: Without irreducibility assumption on $X'$, no even with $G,H$ reductive.
Let $G=\mathrm{GL}_1$ act on the 1-dimensional affine space $X$ by homotheties: $t\cdot x=tx$. Let $H$ be the trivial subgroup. Let $X'=\{0,1\}$. The $X'$ meets each $G$-orbit in a singleton, that is an $H$-orbit. 
But $k[X]^G$ is reduced to constants, while $k[X']^H\simeq k\times k$ is not.

Comment: Only demanding closed orbits will not suffice. Take $X$ to be the 2-dimensional affine, $G$ the upper left unipotent group, $X'$ the union of the axes and $H$ trivial.